# How to override org.springframework.hateoas.Resources serialize content as List to serialize the name

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-hateoas

Jackson is serializing lists with no type erasure. When a GET method returns a Resources object,Is it possible to override to remove the type from Resources

```
{ 
"_embedded": {
    "customObjList": [
        {
            "fld1": "a",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://..."
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

expected

```
{ 
"_embedded": {
    "customObj": [
        {
            "fld1": "a",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://..."
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Relation` on Resource class to change the default collection name

```
@Relation(collectionRelation = "customObj")
class CustomObjResource{ 
   ...
}
```